# How to realize Undo drawing for both polygon and line in Openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I am new to Openlayers3.

I have tried to find a lot of references on the internet. This is only one similar problem [undo last point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152119/undo-last-point-when-drawing-linestring-possible-regression) I can find. But it is only working for linestring. Is there a way to realize undo function for both line and polygon? If it can be realize with some better ways, that is also fine for me.

If it can't be realize, is there a way to undo last feature instead of last point while drawing?

I am very appreciate if there is a working jsfiddle can be provided.